# Easiest way to store Excel invoice data into SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, excel

I want to link an invoice template in Excel to a SQL Server database.

The invoice currently contains only a few very basic fields like user/customer/date/item-id/description/quantity/Total etc.

In future more fields will be required.

What's the easiest way to store all that invoice data in realtime to a SQL Server database when the user presses enter in the invoice?

How many tables will I need to create in SQL Server?

The end users are not tech savvy at all, I need to deploy this solution without any technical requirements from them.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to create an SSIS package that sucks up the excel spreadsheet and captures the data say once a day. The excel file will need to be in the same location, say a network folder and the structure will also have to be the same, meaning the columns and their names once setup will have to also be the same. Otherwise, it's best to have something like a web front end or a fat32 client (basically build an app in Visual Studio or something) that allows data input directory to the SQL server.

Check out this link to learn about it:

http://knowlton-group.com/using-ssis-to-export-data-to-excel/